# in mvc, using summernote editor, i wanna send data which contents string and html to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, summernote

I'm starter at MVC so there are some points I cant do. Summernote Editor is used to write blog and Ajax is used to post. After inside this editor some characters are written, this html data inside smmernote editor and other string data must be posted with ajax but i was not able to send data to controller.

HTML section

```
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="frmCreateBlogEntry">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTitle" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="250" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtSubtitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">subtitle</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="txtSubtitle" id="txtSubtitle" placeholder="enter subtitle" maxlength="250" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="smrntContent" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Blog Entry</label>
                    <div  class="col-sm-10">
                        <div id="smrntContent" class="form-control summernote" name="smrntContent"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <button id="btnPreview" type="button" class="btn btn-yellow pull-right">preview</button>
                    <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Script section

```
$(document).ready(function () {          
        $("#smrntContent").summernote({
                "height": 200
        });
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            var markupStr = $("#smrntContent").summernote('code');
            var createBlogEntry =
                    {
                        Title: $("#txtTitle").val(),
                        Subtitle: $("#txtTitle").val(),
                        Content: markupStr
                    };
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Yayin/CreateNewBlogEntry",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "json",
                data: createBlogEntry,
                success: function (response) {
                    //Başarılı bir şekilde kaydedildi ise
                    if (response.Success) {
                    }                       
                    else {                            
                    }
                },                    
                error: function (xhr, status) {                        
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Controller section

```
        public JsonResult CreateNewBlogEntry(BlogEntry createBlogEntry)
    {
        try
        {               
            createBlogEntry.CreatedBy = (SessionManager.ActiveAdmin != null) ? SessionManager.ActiveAdmin.DisplayName : SessionManager.ActiveUser.DisplayName;
            createBlogEntry.IsActive = false; 

            _blogEntryRepo.Insert(createBlogEntry);

            _uow.Save();

            return Json(new { Success = true, Message = ".." });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Success = false, Message = ".." + ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

I wonder if I might write something for (datatype:) at ajax section

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally solved this, myself. Before sending data to the controller that is before ajax section, I used `encodeURIComponent` function.

```
var markupStr = encodeURIComponent($("#smrntContent").summernote('code'));
```

([Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.as))

Comment: how you can decode it then? and in this case having summernote is useless.